# how to 'id' disable in query or html or css

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want "id" disable @media(min-width:768px).i want this id don't work this media query..

id name"dl-menu"
how to do?
Please help anyone..
thank u!
[image]

Comment: `div`s are never disabled, you can toggle their view for different viewports, but not disable them. Please rephrase your question it is unclear, and add some code you are trying to create

Comment: <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
    <button class="dl-trigger">Home</button>
    <ul class="dl-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Fashion<span class="carot"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span></a>          
        </li>            
    </ul>
</div>

Comment: http://problem.hasan24.com/
please go to visit this link..
when mouse cursor move this menu then show the sub-menu.then extran menu show .this name back
i don't need show back option this full width @media(min-width:768px).
this back option show because "dl-menu" work
so,i want #dl-menu  not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to hide the div. If so, you can just use `display: none`:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #dl-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Also, add when you want to show in other media query:

```
#dl-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: i want display always show.because "dl-menuwrapper" always work,
#dl-menu connect the javascript.
this is problem
i want dl-menuwrapper class always active and id="#dl-menu" not effect my dl-menuwrapper div.

Comment: Which means you want to disable javascript actions when the width is 768px, am I?

Comment: problem.hasan24.com  please go to visit this link.. when mouse cursor move this menu then show the sub-menu.then extran menu show .this name back i don't need show back option this full width @media(min-width:768px). this back option show because "dl-menu" work so,i want #dl-menu not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide it:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #dl-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: i want display always show.because "dl-menuwrapper" always work,
#dl-menu connect the javascript.
this is problem
i want dl-menuwrapper class always active and id="#dl-menu" not effect my dl-menuwrapper div.

Comment: problem.hasan24.com please go to visit this link.. when mouse cursor move this menu then show the sub-menu.then extran menu show .this name back i don't need show back option this full width @media(min-width:768px). this back option show because "dl-menu" work so,i want #dl-menu not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media(min-width:768px) {
    #id-menu {
        display:none;
    } 
 }
```

Use this media query in your CSS file.

Comment: i am use this code.i don't hidden display.
class always active. but only div not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple CSS statement to disable events

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #dl-menu {
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}
```

Comment: problem.hasan24.com please go to visit this link.. when mouse cursor move this menu then show the sub-menu.then extran menu show .this name back i don't need show back option this full width @media(min-width:768px). this back option show because "dl-menu" work so,i want #dl-menu not work.